# Add, save data from MFC App(Visual Studio 2015) to SQL Server

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-studio

I am beginner in using Visual Studio. I've had learnt on displaying data from SQL Server in ASP.NET web application. Now I want to display data with MFC Application(Project type). I don't know  how to start make the button functioning which is to save any text to database. Compared to ASP.NET, it offers toolbox Grid View that easily display data but not in MFC App. Currently I just have a .rc file that being designed its interface. I got SQL Server Management Studio to use. I take a look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mfc/mfc_database_classes.htm but the guidance not complete. I need a step by step and complete tutorial on how to add, save data into SQL Server using MFC Application at Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class in your **MFC Application** of type **ODBC Customer**. Right click on your "Header Files" folder in the Solution Explorer and click "Add Class". Select the option "*MFC*" and select "*MFC ODBC Customer*". Then you are asked to select your data source. Assuming that you haven't created any data source till now, click "*New*". Select your database driver type and then type the location where you want to save your data source. After saving, you will be asked the names of the server you wish to connect to and a description of your data source. After clicking "*Next*", you are asked about the authentication. I prefer "***SQL Server Authentication using login id***". Provide username and password. After "*Next*", you can select your database from the server or attach a database to the server. Click "*Next*" and you are moved to some optional selections. It is fine to let them be and click "*Finish*". You will now have a class which is used to add,read or delete data in the database.